# How to ignore folders to send in docker build context

Tags: docker, docker-build

I am facing an issue of large docker build context because of my project structure. In my root directory I have lib folder for common code and folders of micro-services. Now I want to build for miscroservice1 to include only lib folder and to ignore other microservices.

I am running docker build command in root folder because running command in microservice folder giving error Forbidden path outside the build context

```
rootFolder
-- lib
-- microservice1/Dockerfile
-- microservice2/Dockerfile
-- microservice3/Dockerfile
```

I have two solutions but didn't try for now

1. To add symlinks for lib in my microservice folder
2. To write script for each docker build to add lib folder in specific microservice folder and then run docker build.

I am trying the above two solutions. Can anyone suggest any best practice?

Comment: Have you tried a .dockerignore file?

Comment: .dockerignore will not resolve this because I need to include specific folders based on build for specific microservice and in my case I need to add .dockerignore in root folder and that should be only one

Answer (score 60):

You can create `.dockerignore` in your root directory and add

```
microservice1/
microservice2/
microservice3/
```

to it, just like `.gitignore` does during tracking files, docker will ignore these folders/files during the build.

## Update

You can include `docker-compose.yml` file in your root directory, look at [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for all the options, such as setting `environment`, running a specific command, etc, that you can use during the build process.

```
version: "3"
services:
  microservice1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./microservice1/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./path/to/share:/path/to/mount/on/container"
    ports:
      - "<host>:<container>"
    links:
      - rootservice # defines a dns record in /etc/hosts to point to rootservice
  microservice2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./microservice2/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./path/to/share:/path/to/mount/on/container"
    ports:
      - "<host>:<container>"
    links:
      - rootservice # defines a dns record in /etc/hosts to point to rootservice
      - microservice1
  rootservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./path/to/share:/path/to/mount/on/container"
    ports:
      - "<host>:<container>"
    depends_on:
      - microservice1
      - microservice2
    ports:
      - "<host1>:<container1>"
      - "<host2>:<container2>"
```

This will be your build recipe for your `microservices`, you can now run `docker-compose build` to build all your images.

Comment: When I will run build for microservice1. Do this folder will include in build?

Comment: since you have `Dockerfile` for each of the service you'll have to build each service separately.

Comment: If you know the `microservice` architecture, which says every microservice has to be its separate image, and all the services communicate over IP protocol, which means that each service has to be built separately and deployed separately.
if you want to build all you services using a single command or define relation between different services you might wanna look at [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Comment: but .dockerignore will be one for all builds

Comment: @IbtesamLatif not really, each docker workspace can have their own `.dockerignore`, which means your microservice1 can have its own `.dockerignore`

Comment: Where I need to run docker build command for microservice1. In root folder or in microservice1 folder?

Comment: @IbtesamLatif I think you need a mix of `.dockerignore` and `docker-compose` solution.

Comment: @IbtesamLatif I have updated my answer, to include the solution that I was proposing, this is to circumvent the script that you wanted to write.

Comment: I have fixed it by adding my custom script that will run in my docker build to include required folders

Comment: Unfortunately it is suboptimal because the context will be shared for all microservices, which leads to cache misses if other microservice change

Answer (score 5):

If the only tool you have is Docker, there aren't very many choices.  The key problem is that there is only one `.dockerignore` file.  That means you always have to use your project root directory as the Docker context directory (including every services' sources), but you can tell Docker which specific Dockerfile within that to use.  (Note that all `COPY` directives will be relative to the `rootFolder` in this case.)

```sh
docker build rootFolder -f microservice1/Dockerfile -t micro/service1:20190831.01
```

In many languages there is a way to package up the library (C `.a`, `.h`, and `.so` files; Java `.jar` files; Python wheels; ...).  If your language supports that, another option is to build the library, then copy (not symlink) the library into each service's build tree.  Using Python's wheel format as an example:

```sh
pip wheel ./lib
cp microlib.whl microservice1
docker build microservice1 -t micro/service1:20190831.01
# Dockerfile needs to
# RUN pip install ./microlib.whl
```

Another useful variant on this is a manual multi-stage build.  You can have `lib/Dockerfile` pick some base image, and then install the library into that base image.  Then each service's `Dockerfile` starts `FROM` the library image, and has it preinstalled.  Using a C library as an example:

```sh
# I am lib/Dockerfile

# Build stage
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS build
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./ ./
RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make
# This is a typical pattern implemented by GNU Autoconf:
# it actually writes files into /src/out/usr/local/...
RUN make install DESTDIR=/src/out

# Install stage -- service images are based on this
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY --from=build /src/out /
RUN ldconfig
```

```sh
# I am microservice1/Dockerfile
ARG VERSION=latest
FROM micro/lib:${VERSION}
# From the base image, there are already
# /usr/local/include/microlib.h and /usr/local/lib/libmicro.so
COPY ...
RUN gcc ... -lmicro
CMD ...
```

There is also usually an option (again, depending on your language and its packaging system) to upload your built library to some server, possibly one you're running yourself.  (A Python pip `requirements.txt` file can contain an arbitrary HTTP URL for a wheel, for example.)  If you do this then you can just declare your library as an ordinary dependency, and this problem goes away.

Which of these works better for you depends on your language and runtime, and how much automation of multiple coordinated `docker build` commands you're willing to do.